# Running Docker container on a specific port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, digital-ocean, dokku

I have a Rails app deployed with Dokku on DigitalOcean. I've created a Postgres database and linked it with a Rails app. Everything worked fine until I restarted the droplet. I figured out that apps stopped working because on restart every Docker container gets a new port and Rails application isn't able to connect to it. If I run `dokku postgresql:info myapp` it shows the old port, but it has changed. If I manually change database.yml and push it to the dokku repo everything works.

So how do I prevent Docker from assigning different port each time the server restarts? Or maybe there is an option to change ports of running containers.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have much experience with Dokku but for docker there's no such thing of A container's port.
In docker you can expose a container's port to receive incoming request and map it to specific ports in your host machine.
With that you can, for instance, run your postgres inside a container and tell docker that you wanna expose the 5432, default postgresql port, to receive incoming requests:

```
sudo docker run --expose=5432 -P <IMAGE> <COMMAND>
```

The `--expose=5432` tells docker to expose the port 5432 to receive incoming connections from outside world.
The `-P` flag tells docker to map all exposed ports in your container to the host machine's port.
with that you can connect to postgres pointing to your host's ip:port.
If you want to map a container's port to a different host machine port you can use the -p flag:

```
sudo docker run --expose=5432 -p=666 <IMAGE> <COMMAND>
```

Not sure if this can help you with Dokku environment, but I hope so.
For more information about docker's run command see: https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#run

Comment: Thank you for the contribution! So what would be the command to run a Postgres container on a specific port? What's the difference between `-P` and `--expose` ports? Right now I have a Postgres image that runs on `0.0.0.0:49156->5432` and I want it to be `0.0.0.0:49168->5432`, what would be the command?

Comment: Documentation about -P and --expose https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports

Comment: `--expose`, you tell docker that you wanna receive connections on a specific container's port.
`-P`, you wanna map all exposed container's port to host machine ports.
To map to different ports you can't use `-P`, you have to use `-p`:
`sudo docker --expose=5432 -p=49156:5432 <IMAGE> <COMMAND>`

Comment: @RogerAlmeida Does -p=YYYY:XXXX imply --expose on port XXXX ?

Comment: @RogerAlmeida My image looks like this: `IMAGE: postgresql/blog:latest, COMMAND: /usr/bin/start_pgsql, PORT: 0.0.0.0:49156->5432/tcp`. So I want to change port to 49168. `docker run -p=49168:5432 postgresql/blog:latest /usr/bin/start_pgsql` returns `stat /usr/bin/start_pgsql: no such file or directory`

Comment: In other words: what should be in place of `<COMMAND>` option? This image was started by dokku plugin and I have no idea how to stop and start it again.